# Logback to Logstash encoding error

Tags: encoding, logstash, logback, elastic-stack, logstash-logback-encoder

I am using Logback to send logs from my Grails application to an ELK stack.

My logback appender

```
appender("tcp", LogstashTcpSocketAppender) {
  destination = "localhost:5044"
  SSLConfiguration aSsl = new SSLConfiguration()
  aSsl.trustStore = new KeyStoreFactoryBean()
  aSsl.trustStore.location = "classpath:logstashTrustStore.jks"
  aSsl.trustStore.password = "test123"
  if(aSsl.trustStore instanceof LifeCycle)
    aSsl.trustStore.start()
  if(aSsl instanceof LifeCycle)
    aSsl.start()
  ssl = aSsl

  encoder(LogstashEncoder) {
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  }
}
```

My logstash input config is

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5044
    mode => "server"
    type => log4j
  }
}
```

When I start my application the logs are sent to the ELK stack, but I get the following warning

```
[2017-01-22T10:57:14,801][WARN ][logstash.codecs.line     ] Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"\\a\\xDCl\\x86\\xFEڐ\\xD1\\u0006\\x92J\\xBDMTLN\\xBF@\\x93\\x9B\\x8E\\xC1\\xE8&\\xF5|\\xF1\\xF4\\u0000\\u0000:\\xC0#\\xC0'\\u0000<\\xC0%\\xC0)\\u0000g\\u0000@\\xC0\\t\\xC0\\u0013\\u0000/\\xC0\\u0004\\xC0\\u000E\\u00003\\u00002\\xC0+\\xC0/\\u0000\\x9C\\xC0-\\xC01\\u0000\\x9E\\u0000\\xA2\\xC0\\b\\xC0\\u0012\\u0000", :expected_charset=>"UTF-8"}
```

The logs I can see in Kibana only contain messages like that, but I don't understand where the encoding error could come from, as I configured my log appender to use UTF-8 and Logstash seems to be expecting UTF-8.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default charset is UTF-8 and you might need to set the correct ***charset*** within your `input` something like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5044
    mode => "server"
    type => log4j
    codec => plain {
       charset => "ISO-8859-1"
    }
  }
}
```

The available [charsets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-plain.html#plugins-codecs-plain-charset). You could have a look at this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2881) for more. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am pretty sure, that my LogstashEncoder is sending the data in UTF-8 encoding, as I have explicitly the encoding for the encoder. I also used this encoder to write to a file and the encoding there is definitely UTF-8